# Lebesgue integration involving double integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was asked to find the Lebesgue integral of the following:

$$\int_0^2 \int_{y^2}^4 y \cdot \cos(x^2) dxdy.$$

Now, its not hard to compute that the Riemann integral is $$\int_0^2 \int_{y^2}^4 y \cdot \cos(x^2) dxdy = \frac{ \sin(16)}{4}$$

Knowing that the Lebesgue integral agrees with the Reimann integral will give me what I am looking for, however; in the spirt of preciseness, is there anything that would need to be stated regarding the function  $f(x,y) = y \cdot \cos(x^2)$ Lebasgue integrability? Would Fubini and Tonelli need to be invoked as those always seem to be invoked when double integration is involved.

Comment: A product of measurable maps is measurable. A product of bounded measurable maps over a finite measure space is integrable.

Comment: There's no need to go back to Riemann integrals. What you *really* use when computing Riemann integrals is the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*... you rarely go back to the definition in terms of Riemann sums. The Lebesgue integral is similar: it also has a version of FTC (which is actually much stronger), so you can integrate as always. Here, $f$ is continuous and you're integrating over a bounded (obviously Lebesgue measurable) subset of the plane, so everything works out.